# Blackberry RSA algorithm implementation?

Tags: java, blackberry, rsa

Does anyone know good example or API documentation of RSA implementation for Blackberry platform?

My task is encrypt-decrypt conversation between server and device on own protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The BlackBerry API provides RSA encryption.  Check [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/RSAEncryptorEngine.html).  The only thing is that to use those classes on a real device you need to sign your app with the Certicom key.